# Possible usage of an automated compiler error fixing plugin

Tags: java, compiler-errors, code-reuse

I am working on a project aims to make software reuse easier. The final project provides a framework to select a desired feature from a (Java, C++) program and adds that to the another program.

I am responsible for two parts of the project.

1. Fixing possible compiler errors after the desired feature is added to the another program.
2. Changing the desired feature to be usable in its new location. In this case the program should pass successfully all test cases (not details at the moment as my question is related to Section 1).

Currently, I implemented the first step and the program can automatically fix possible compiler errors after the desired feature is added to its new location. It almost supports all Java compiler errors (even that some of them never happen in the above project), and in few of cases a user needs to help the plugin to fix the compiler error.

Note that the plugin has access to both programs and using these information it will fix compiler errors. 
For clarity, as a very simple example in a case that there is a dependency between the desired feature with a library in its original location, the plugin tries to fix the compiler error for example by adding that library to the program.

I know current IDEs provide suggestions in a case that there is a compiler error in the program, but the advantage of the current plugin is that it automatically can fix compiler errors, and does not provide a list of solutions to the user for each compiler error.

The question That I am facing is that: Any one could please mention other situations that I can use the implemented automated compiler error fixing plugin? (of course except the above project). Any suggestion is welcome as it helps me to see other directions of the project.

Comment: Helping answer compiler error questions on SO would ironically be applicable in this case.

Comment: Note that if the plugin has no access to the first program, then it is capable of fixing only some kind of compiler errors. For example, if it has access to a library from program 1 and program 1 is not accessible then it cannot fix the error.